# Strategies for heavily over-constrained scheduling

Tags: optaplanner

Trying to schedule 1000 observations (of the same duration for now) into 500 time slots, hence only half of them will fit. Using planning entity "Observation" with nullable planning variable "timeSlot". Constraints expressed as ConstraintStream

- `observation1.timeSlot != observation2.timeSlot`, if not penalise 1hard
- `observation.timeSlot != null`, if `null` penalise with 1medium

Termination after 10min or when feasible solution is found

**Findings**

1. Scheduling 501 observations into 500 slots terminates after 16s with 0hard/-1medium. This is expected.
2. Scheduling 1000 observations into 500 slots terminates after 10m with -499hard/-1medium. This is totally unexpected. I would expect 0hard/-500medium, or at least something going towards that direction.

What are the necessary measures to make optaplanner do the right thing?

Constraints

```
    Constraint notSameSlot(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        constraintFactory.fromUniquePair(OB.class)
            .filter({ ob1, ob2 -> ob1.start == ob2.start })
            .penalize("overlap", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
    }

    Constraint notAssignable(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        constraintFactory.fromUnfiltered(OB.class)
            .filter(ob -> ob.start == null)
            .penalize("not assignable", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM)
    }
```

Planning Entity

```
@PlanningEntity
public class OB {
    @PlanningVariable(nullable = true, valueRangeProviderRefs = "timeslotRange")
    Timeslot start
    @PlanningId
    int obId
    OB(int obId) {this.obId = obId }
    OB() {} // required by Optaplanner, not sure why
}
```

Timeslot

```
class Timeslot {
    @PlanningId
    int slot

    Timeslot(int slot) {
        this.slot = slot
    }
}
```

PlanningSolution

```
@PlanningSolution
class Schedule {
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "timeslotRange")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty 
    List<Timeslot> timeslots

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    List<OB> observations

    @PlanningScore
    HardMediumSoftScore score
}
```

UPDATE: added null checking to the `notSameSlot` constraint, I was unaware that `fromUniquePairs` passed unassigned entities. This changes the result, but not to the better. Now, no slot is assigned at all. The result now is 0hard/-1000medium/0soft

```
Constraint notSameSlot(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
     constraintFactory.fromUniquePair(OB.class)
            .filter({ ob1, ob2 ->
                ob1.start !== null &&
                ob2.start !== null &&
                ob1.start.slot == ob2.start.slot
            })
            .penalize("overlap", HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
    }
```

Comment: I would run it with optaplanner-benchmark and look at the best score graphs of both those findings. Then ask questions like: did finding 1 start with hard constraints broken after the Construction Heuristic? Did Local Search solve them. Why does the CH assign values if it breaks hard constraints while it can choose to not assign them instead? (See TRACE logging for that latter)

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey, I did try benchmark. But it only shows empty plots, because only a single solution is found. This is the equivalent of pick "500 random things out of 1000 and throw each of them into one of 500 buckets, one each". I would have hoped this to be more straightforward to do and understand.

Comment: If only a single dot is plotted (and it's earlier than your termination time, so you don't have `init` in your score), it means none of the out-of the-box move selectors (change and swap moves) yield any improvements, that is very strange. Run in TRACE logging and see what happens after CH ended during the LS traces.

Comment: At first sight, it sounds like a bug in your constraints: something that is penalized that should not be. Do you have a unit test with ConstraintVerifier (see docs)?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet I added relevant source code above, including the rather trivial constraints. I would appreciate if you could have a quick look at the constraints. What could be wrong about that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I had

```
<termination>
    <unimprovedSpentLimit>PT2M30S</unimprovedSpentLimit>
    <bestScoreFeasible>true</bestScoreFeasible>
</termination>
```

as termination criteria. I did not understand that bestScoreFeasible means that as soon as no hard constraint is violated, the solver terminates, which results in no slots being assigned because that is still considered a feasible solution. Removing the second criterion solves the issue.